# After I enter an input in python, how do I clear it from my CLI?

Tags: python-3.x, input, text

In a script like this:

```
inp = input('')
print(inp)
```

When I run it, I enter my text and get it back:

```
$python3 test.py

Hello            (keyboard input)
Hello            (Print command)
```

But how do I get the result more like this after I press enter:?

```
$python3 test.py

Hello            (Print command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options. The most straightforward one is to omit the print statement and just use:

```
inp = input('')
```

If you'd like to hide the input from the terminal as you're typing, you may use getpass():

```
from getpass import getpass
inp = getpass()
print(inp)
```

Or you may clear the whole terminal after reading the input like so:

```
import os

inp = input('')
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print(inp)
```

Or just delete the last line - I think this is the solution you're looking for:

```
inp = input('')
print ("\033[A                             \033[A")
print(inp)
```